# Are there any apparent flaws in the methodology of Wilhelm et. al. 2016?

Tags: placebo

[Wilhelm et. al. 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27865824) is a meta-analysis of 23 placebo controlled beta-blocker studies. The attempt of the study was to indicate what fraction of the beta-blocker's effect was due to the placebo effect.

In a discussion with another person, a few issues have come up. First, he feels uncomfortable with the variability of the study designs for the 23 studies used. I see that as being a necessary component of the analysis, as it is seeing if different methodologies yield different results.

He claims the studies are not randomized, but they do seem to be randomly selected, just controlled for certain requirements in order to perform the moderator analysis.

The conclusion also seems reasonable: if study quality improvement yields stronger results, the logical conclusion is that the effect is real and not due to some kind of statistical noise.

Am I accidentally ignoring the flaws, or are they simply not there?

Comment: Just want to check, does anyone think if this would be better asked on research or biology stackexchange?

Comment: In my opinion, it’s fine, but due to low activity on the site, you might not get an answer.

Comment: Nice question, although you'll need indeed patience for an answer. If you want to ask *about it* elsewhere then make sure to vary the focus sufficiently to avoid a frowned upon cross-post.

Comment: Exactly why I asked this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303690/multiple-se-posting-progress?noredirect=1#comment987367_303690

Comment: Sadly it was originally worded in such a way as to be a duplicate and of course once downvoting starts, it seems to be a one way street.

Comment: I added a more generic question in the academic SE. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/99496/are-meta-analyses-a-scientifically-robust-form-of-investigation